# Ubuntu One Installation error - W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS_Precise

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, ubuntu-one

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubunto 12.04.2 LTS_Precise Pangolin_-Release amd64(20130213)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT.apt-get update cannont be used to add new CD-ROMs

W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS_Precise Pangolin_-Release amd64(201302213)/dists/precise/restriced binary-i386/Packages Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT.-get update connot be used to add new CD-ROMs, E:Some index files failed to download they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Yes my laptop CD-ROM is not working, and I assume that has something to do with this install not working. I don't want to have to fix my CD-ROM drive to get this to install and my BIOS does not support disabling it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open the `software-properties-gtk` program, and delete the `CD-ROM` source option from the list. Then quit, and run `sudo apt-get update` in a Terminal.

The CD-ROM isn't required, but network access will be.